# Accelerometer shake make sound only once?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to implement a function that detects a user shaking his/her iPhone, and then the app will make a barking sound. So far I've got the code attached below, and it works. But, if I shake the phone harder, it makes 2 or more barks one immediately after the other. How do I make sure this only happens once per shake, no matter how hard?

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer 
    didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
        if (acceleration.x > kAccelerationThreshold ||
            acceleration.y > kAccelerationThreshold ||
            acceleration.z > kAccelerationThreshold) {
            // BARKING SOUND
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an NSTimer - look here: [section "Timer"](http://www.iphoneexamples.com/)

After playing the sound, set a boolean variable called "hasBarked" to YES and call the timer then. After two seconds, the timer sets "hasBarked" to NO and disables itself.
Finally, put the whole sound-playing method into an if block that only plays the sound if "hasBarked" is NO.

Comment: Interesting solution.  The trade off between my solution and yours is the NSTimer solution presumably either spawns a thread or uses an OS/hardware timer (which would depend on the NSTimer implementation).  The time() solution has the added cost of an OS call every time it checks the acceleration (which means a task switch).

Answer (score 3):

Why not keep a value around with the last time you played the sound?

```
time_t last_time_played_bark = 0;


#define MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_BARKS 5   // in seconds
time_t now = time(NULL);

if (last_time_played_bark + MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_BARKS < now) {
    // BARKING_SOUND
    last_time_played_bark = now;
}
```

Presumably you'll want MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_BARKS to be at least as long as it takes to play the sound.

Comment: Hold on.. is that a Java function? This won't work in objective-C:

time_t now = time();

Comment: Ah, forgot the parameter to time().  Fixed example.

Comment: Yes, time() is a standard C call.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, if you just want to detect shake gestures, you might find it easier to use the [motion events added in OS 3.0](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW24) than trying to roll your own from raw accelerometer data.

I agree with Epsilon Prime's suggestion to store the timestamp of the last time you played the sound as a means to throttle how often you play it.